# Find the shortest distance from the point P = (2,2,5)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the shortest distance from the point $P = (2,2,5)$ to a point on the line given by $l:(x,y,z) = (-6t, -5t, -4t)$

So I've got the matrix that I think it should look like which is

$\begin{bmatrix}-6&-5&-4\\2&2&5\end{bmatrix}$ but what exactly am I solving here

Comment: Try Googling "shortest distance from point to a line".  This is a standard linear algebra problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I posted it and people aren;t liking it so I want to get rid of it because they keep hurting my rep by giving me downvotes

Comment: You don't have enough rep to cast close votes, yet.  But to be nice, I guess I'll cast one for you.  If 4 more people decide to do the same, then this question will be closed.

Comment: No need to close it now @Bye_World

Comment: OK.  I've retracted the vote then.  Note that now I won't be able to vote to close again if you change your mind.

Comment: Thanks. I decided that it will be worth my terribly worded question getting downvotes because @user84413 provided a linear algebra solution that is needed so maybe someone else can use this to help them ya know?

Comment: That's fine.  Just so you know, though, this is such a common exercise that $1)$ it's [been asked here before](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=distance+point+line+is%3Aquestion+%5Blinear-algebra%5D) (many times) and $2)$ it even has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) where the [very last section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Another_vector_formulation) gives user84413's solution (though I do wish they'd have used the actual cross symbol $\times$ for the cross product rather than the wedge symbol $\wedge$).

Comment: Oh ok. Well shucks, in that case I'll close it @Bye_World

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $u=\langle 2,2,5\rangle$ and $v=\langle 6,5,4\rangle$, and find $\displaystyle d=\frac{|u\times v|}{|v|}$.

Answer (score 0):

The distance from $P$ to the point on $l$ at time $t$ will be given by:

$$d(t) = \displaystyle \sqrt{(2+6t)^2 + (2+5t)^2 + (5 + 4t)^2}$$

So our problem can be solved like a standard minimization problem from calculus: the value of $t$ that minimizes $d(t)$ corresponds to the point on the line closest to $P$.  However, taking the derivative of $d(t)$ is hard due to the square root.  Instead, you can minimize the function $(d(t))^2$, which is much easier.  This is valid since a value of $t$ minimizes $d(t) \iff$ it minimizes $(d(t))^2$.

---

**Alternative method**:

The vector $ \langle 2, 2, 5 \rangle$, the line $l$, and the line segment that represents the shortest distance between the two forms a right triangle with the origin as one of its vertices.  The hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{2^2 + 2^2 + 5^2} = \sqrt{33}$.

The length of the leg of the triangle given by the projection of the vector $P$ onto the line will be equal to $\sqrt{33} \cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle formed between vector $P$ and the line.  How can we find this distance?

Let $\hat{ \mathbf{l} }$ be the unit vector pointing in the direction of the line into the $(+, +, +)$ octant.  By the properties of dot product, we have $\langle 2, 2, 5 \rangle \cdot \hat{ \mathbf{ l } } = | \langle 2, 2, 5 \rangle | | \hat{ \mathbf{ l } } | \cos( \theta) = \sqrt{33} \cos( \theta)$, so computing the dot product gives you the length of that leg of the triangle.  Finally, you can find the length of the second leg of the triangle (the shortest distance between $l$ and $P$) by using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: The derivative of $d(t) = 0$

Comment: I'm recommending minimizing $f(t) = (d(t))^2$ by first finding $\displaystyle \frac{df}{dt}$.

Comment: there is no $f$

Comment: I'm just defining it to be the function $(d(t))^2$ for notational convenience.

Comment: This is not a calculus class, this is linear algebra. Shouldn't have to use any sort of calculus for this

Comment: That's alright; you don't have to accept my answer, and we can wait on someone else.  I believe in having diverse solutions posted nevertheless.